# I am changing my start up activity from "MainActivity" to "RealMain" I declared this in the manifest but alas MainActivity

Tags: android, class, android-manifest

I am changing my start up activity from "MainActivity" to "RealMain" I declared this in the manifest but alas MainActivity is still coming up first. Can anybody enlighten me? The code is from my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.fyp2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name=""/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".realMain"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" ></activity>

</application>
```

`

Comment: try doing Project > Clean in Eclipse, sometimes that fixes odd behavior.

Comment: also tried that already...strange.

Comment: .RealMain case sensitive. Check your package name in manifest

Answer (score 1):

In this cas i always use the entire namespace

```
android:name=".realMain"
```

could be wrong, so use:

```
android:name="com.myproject.realMain"
```

it works for me.

Also using naming convetion is always a good thing: so I suggest also to use `RealMain` as the name of your class (**Upper case** first letter).

I suggest also to keep manifext.xml clean. Remove

```
<uses-permission android:name=""/>
```

...does nothing at all.